# How to get the ProcessThread ID from the currently executing Thread object?

Tags: c#, .net

*I read the CLR via C# book by Jeffrey Richter. Right now I read the chapter about threads. Author writes that a threat in CLR exactly matches to thread in Windows OS. Therefore it is interesting for me how to get the real id of Thread instance*

[ProcessThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread(v=vs.110).aspx) class instance contains [Id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.id(v=vs.110).aspx) property. It is the *real* ID of a thread in Windows OS. I need to get the same Id value for the [Thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) instance.

The values of [Thread.ManagedThreadId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentmanagedthreadid(v=vs.110).aspx) while identical to each other don't match any of the ProcessThread objects returned by [Process.Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example

```
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
```

Will print `11` in both cases while the minimum Id of the ProcessThread objects in `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` starts at 4700

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169955/discussion-on-question-by-andrey-bushman-how-to-get-the-processthread-id-from-th).